# Are cores divded in OpenMP in nested loops?

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

Let's suppose that we have this code:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<5; i++){
  //do something expensive here
  for(size_t i=0; i<5; i++){
    //do somehting expensive here too
  }
}
```

Let's suppose we have at least 25 physical cores. How can we exploit all of them? A `collapse` would be not possible because the first expensive computation. What would be the most efficient solution in this case?

Comment: It makes no sense to use size_t when int is sure to work.  Not certain of your question or what is your objection to mop_nested.

Answer (score 0):

Just decouple the loops.  If your current code is

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
  expensive_1(i);
  for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
  {
    expensive_2(j);
  }
}
```

then make it into this, possibly saving the results of `expensive_1` if they are needed in `expensive_2`.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
  expensive_1(i);
}

#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
  {
    expensive_2(j);
  }
}
```

Comment: Surely you wanted a collapse(2) on the second parallel for?